# Is Windows.Media.Ocr API available on Windows IoT Core with RaspberryPi 2?

Tags: ocr, raspberry-pi2, iot

I checked out many places for the answer but couldn't get one. According to [this](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/UnavailableApis.htm) page the API should be available. But, when I run the codes on RaspberryPi 2, I get Unhandled Exception Error. To ensure that my codes are correct I ran the codes on my local machine, it runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Windows.Media.Ocr is universal API, so it is available.
With RaspberryPy there are no any language resources installed on device.
On such device, if you try code like following, ocrEngine will be null.

```
var ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(new Language("en"));
```

You can check for available language recognizers with [OcrEngine.AvailableRecognizerLanguages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.ocr.ocrengine.availablerecognizerlanguages.aspx) property.